# Javascript Images with If/else statement

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement

I am thinking there is something wrong with my if/else statement that is making this code not work. I have tried changing the id and also using document.canvas.src instead of getElementById but it wont work either way for me.

UPDATE: Below is the code I used to get it to function properly:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type = "text/javascript">


function displayImage(whichImage) 
{
    if(whichImage != "noImage")
    {
        document.canvas.src= whichImage;
    }
    else{
        document.canvas.src= "blank.jpg";
    }
}


</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<form name="imageForm">
<table border=3>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="imageSelector" onChange="displayImage(this.value)">
    <option value="noImage">Select an Animal
    <option value="dog.jpg">Dog
    <option value="cat.jpg">Cat
    <option value="parrot.jpg">Parrot
    <option value="fish.jpg">Fish
    <option value="alligator.jpg">Alligator
    <option value="mouse.jpg"> Mouse
    <option value="fox.jpg">Fox
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="blank.jpg" name="canvas" id="animal">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: why you dont have closing tag in your options?

Comment: @ OP Your code works fine http://jsbin.com/APApAbI/1/edit @hallie those are optional. Though OP should really add a DOCTYPE.

Comment: Off subject maybe but can you explain why DOCTYPE should be added?

Comment: @user2939622 without a DOCTYPE you put the browser in [Quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode), that is, the browser will try to render the page in IE 5.5 style.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Much appreciated, and will add to my newbie knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it works in IE 10, may be you can try correcting the option tag:

```
<select name="imageSelector" onChange="displayImage(this.value)">
    <option value="noImage">Select an Animal</option>
    <option value="dog.jpg">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat.jpg">Cat</option>
    <option value="parrot.jpg">Parrot</option>
    <option value="fish.jpg">Fish</option>
    <option value="alligator.jpg">Alligator</option>
    <option value="mouse.jpg">Mouse</option>
    <option value="fox.jpg">Fox</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Read the [tag omission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) rules.

Comment: Thank you. I actually made a rookie mistake (which should be okay because I am one) but I did not have my code and images in the same folder.... DOH!